# Cannot install PayPalCheckoutSDK Nuget Package

Tags: .net, paypal, nuget

I am really struggling to install the PayPalCheckoutSDK Nuget package.

On the GitHub https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK
It says the prerequisites are:

- .NET 4.6.1 or later
- An environment which supports TLS 1.2 (see the
  TLS-update site for more information)
- PayPalHttp 1.0.0

So I also just tried installing PayPalHttp and got the same error.

To ensure I wasn't clashing with anything existing I have created a brand new completely empty project that targets 4.7 from the offset. Both packages still give me the same error.

> Could not install package [either]. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I'm at a complete loss as I've removed anything else from the equation and I cannot work out what I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just made a new empty project for TargetFrameworkVersion v4.7.2. Just added nuget PayPal 1.9.1. No error. This comment does not answer your question, sorry. But it confirms it should work. My VS is configured for nugets as "Package Reference", not "Package.config". This could be a difference.

Comment: @GuyatMercator the standard Paypal NuGet package does add fine. This is just concerning PayPalCheckoutSDK and PayPalHttp

Comment: PayPalHttp 1.0.0 and PayPalCheckoutSdk 1.0.3 nugets have been installed without error in my test project. PayPalClient.cs from the samples compiled successfully.

Comment: @GuyatMercator so that suggests there's definitely something unusual about my specific set up then. But I have no idea where to even start with working out what? What version of Visual Studio are you on?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.10.2. My test project is available at http://87.98.252.207/TestPayPal.zip.

Comment: @GuyatMercator thanks for this! I still couldn't get your project to work on my default set-up, but I was not using VS 2019 (I'm on VS 2015 because one of the main projects I work on won't function in anything later) - got 2019 installed, and it works fine! So apparently they are just not compatible with earlier versions of VS! Would have been nice for PayPal to put that in the requirements! Anyway, problem solved, and I'm not sure I would've gotten there without you, so thank you! If you'd like to take credit, I'm happy for you to write an answer and I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same issue trying to install PayPalHTTp and PayPalSDK on Visual Studio 2015. My Fix was opening the project in Visual Studio 2019 , Installing the packages and then reverting back to Visual Studio 2015.